# Is it safe for the ChaCha8 nonce to be deterministic?

Tags: encryption, nonce

ChaCha8 takes a 8 byte nonce (or IV) that should not be the same twice for the same key. Generating this nonce randomly makes me very very nervous for collisions.

Is it safe to generate this nonce deterministically?

For example the first 6 bytes could be the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, with the last 2 bytes being an unsigned counter wrapping around. This will prevent any collisions from happening for 9000 years if no more than 65535 streams get encrypted in a millisecond (things get more complicated if the same encryption key is being used by multiple machines/threads, but let's ignore that for now).

Comment: Use a larger nonce. See XSalsa20. Will post more tomorrow.

Comment: You could [expand the nonce size to 192 bits](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/can-i-use-the-chacha-core-as-a-256-bit-to-256-bit-one-way-function/11215#11215), similar to how XSalsa20 expands the nonce size of Salsa.

Comment: @CodesInChaos "tomorrow" :P

Comment: Procrastination...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. The only requirement for the nonce in Salsa/Chacha is to be unique; being predictable is not an issue, so a counter is fine.

Like CodesInChaos indicated, I believe extending XSalsa20 to XChaCha20 would also work if you want to a larger nonce, but have nothing concrete so will leave the details to him/her.

Answer (score -3):

Looking at the [reference implementation](http://cr.yp.to/streamciphers/timings/estreambench/submissions/salsa20/chacha8/ref/chacha.c), it looks like the IV is 64 bytes, not 8. In `ECRYPT_ivsetup`, it's a pointer to `uint8_t`, which is then treated as a pair of quartets (e.g., 8) of 8-byte values.

Comment: You're misunderstanding something. Input to the permutation is 64 bytes, but that includes key, stream-id(nonce), offset and a constant.

Comment: And chacha operates on 16 words with 4 bytes each. Iv setup sets the offset to 0, and sets the 8 byte nonce.

Comment: Apologies. I wasn't able to find any real documentation on chacha, so went to the source. I've obviously misread something in the implementation.

Comment: While ChaCha doesn't have much documentation, you can look at Salsa20's documentation. They're almost identical.